# How do I convert httr response content from list to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

## Question:

How can I efficiently convert this response data from a list to a dataframe?

### Starting Info:

I'm using an API for DATiQ (market benchmarking service for trucking services).  I get a response object which I use `httr::content()` to give me a list like this (from `dput()`):

```
response_content <- list(Status = "OK", EstimateId = NULL, FmicAllInCPL25 = 820, 
     FmicAllInCPL50 = 919, FmicAllInCPL75 = 1036, 
     RegionalVariability = 2.422, ModelDescription = "2022 Sep Model", 
     RequestUri = "some-irrelevant-url")

> response_content
$Status
[1] "OK"

$EstimateId
NULL

$FmicAllInCPL25
[1] 820

$FmicAllInCPL50
[1] 919

$FmicAllInCPL75
[1] 1036

$RegionalVariability
[1] 2.422

$ModelDescription
[1] "2022 Sep Model"

$RequestUri
[1] "some-irrelevant-url"
```

I'm trying to get this into a dataframe where I keep the datatypes, but I either get dataframe of lists, like this:

```
> df1 <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(response_content, c)))
> df1
  Status EstimateId FmicAllInCPL25 FmicAllInCPL50 FmicAllInCPL75 RegionalVariability ModelDescription          RequestUri
1     OK       NULL            820            919           1036               2.422   2022 Sep Model some-irrelevant-url
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Status             :List of 1
  ..$ Status: chr "OK"
 $ EstimateId         :List of 1
  ..$ EstimateId: NULL
 $ FmicAllInCPL25     :List of 1
  ..$ FmicAllInCPL25: num 820
 $ FmicAllInCPL50     :List of 1
  ..$ FmicAllInCPL50: num 919
 $ FmicAllInCPL75     :List of 1
  ..$ FmicAllInCPL75: num 1036
 $ RegionalVariability:List of 1
  ..$ RegionalVariability: num 2.42
 $ ModelDescription   :List of 1
  ..$ ModelDescription: chr "2022 Sep Model"
 $ RequestUri         :List of 1
  ..$ RequestUri: chr "some-irrelevant-url"
```

...or I get a dataframe with all character types, like this:

```
> df3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, response_content))
> df3
  Status FmicAllInCPL25 FmicAllInCPL50 FmicAllInCPL75 RegionalVariability ModelDescription          RequestUri
1     OK            820            919           1036               2.422   2022 Sep Model some-irrelevant-url
> str(df3)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Status             : chr "OK"
 $ FmicAllInCPL25     : chr "820"
 $ FmicAllInCPL50     : chr "919"
 $ FmicAllInCPL75     : chr "1036"
 $ RegionalVariability: chr "2.422"
 $ ModelDescription   : chr "2022 Sep Model"
 $ RequestUri         : chr "some-irrelevant-url"
```

I could use this latter method, collect all my data and then convert the datatype, but I'm certain  I don't understand how to efficiently wield the R tools available to me.

Comment: What does your `httr` code look like? Part of the problem is that you can't have NULL values in columns of a data.frame. Are you OK translating those to NA values instead?

Comment: @MrFlick -- I didn't think the `httr` code would be relevant and would make the question unnecessarily long.  But the point about NULL is exactly my problem. and I didn't see it.  NA is fine by me, so I'm going to use r2evans' solution below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `list` has one element with length-0 (the `NULL`). If you can accept converting that to `NA`, then:

```r
out <- as.data.frame(lapply(response_content, \(z) if (is.null(z)) NA else z))
out
#   Status EstimateId FmicAllInCPL25 FmicAllInCPL50 FmicAllInCPL75 RegionalVariability ModelDescription          RequestUri
# 1     OK         NA            820            919           1036               2.422   2022 Sep Model some-irrelevant-url

str(out)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  8 variables:
#  $ Status             : chr "OK"
#  $ EstimateId         : logi NA
#  $ FmicAllInCPL25     : num 820
#  $ FmicAllInCPL50     : num 919
#  $ FmicAllInCPL75     : num 1036
#  $ RegionalVariability: num 2.42
#  $ ModelDescription   : chr "2022 Sep Model"
#  $ RequestUri         : chr "some-irrelevant-url"
```

If some elements can have 1-or-more and all elements are not the same length, you have a different problem of determining how to relate them (for instance, repeat to fill or fill with `NA`s).

Comment: I wasn't sensitive to the issue with the NULL value in there.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I almost cut that out of my reprex not realizing how relevant that was and hoping to shorten the question.

Comment: That's a common complication with questions on SO: not including components thinking irrelevance or over-complication. While I am a huge fan of reducing the problem and data to be a "min reprex", the way to catch it is to reduce the code and data to what you think is appropriate _and then verify that the problem remains_. Had you tried with data lacking the `NULL`, it likely would have worked without problem, giving you a clue that the portion you removed was contributing to (or completely causing) the problem. I've started dozens of questions on SO only to self-resolve with this process.